# calculating each line in 2d arrays c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create an array loop using pointers. For example,

```
2 3 1 2 
3 1 2 2
4 3 2 2
```

The number of lines are undetermined so we don't know how many lines of integers there will be. I have these data of integers stored into a pointer variable called "scores". So if I want to access them,

```
scores[0][0] = 2

scores[0][2] = 1
```

I'm trying to create a for loop where it will add each integer divide it by 2 and then add the sum up. So if I implement a function where it does this, i'd expect the value to be

```
4 // (2/2) + (3/2) + (1/2) + (2/2) = 4
4
5.5
```

This is what I have so far, but it's not working.

```
int *total;
int lines;
total = new int[lines]; //lines: how many lines there are (assume it is passed through a parameter)
for (int i=0;i<lines;i++) 
{
     for (int j=0;j<howmany;j++) //howmany is how many integers there are per line (assume it is passed again)
     {
         total[i] = scores[i][j] //not sure how to divide it then accumulate the sum per line and store it
```

Assume that "scores" already hold the data of integers and we're extracting the data of integers elsewhere so the user does not input anything.
I would want to access the calculated sum by doing total[0], total[1], etc..

Comment: Please reformulate what you want the code to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For integer division

```
// (2/2) + (3/2) + (1/2) + (2/2) = 4
this will give 3, not 4
```

this will give you 4

```
// (2 + 3 + 1 + 2 ) / 2 = 4
```

And you are expecting value such as `5.5`, so you should define the result as `float` or `double`

```
float *result;
int lines = 3; // need to initialize local variable before new. for this case, we set the lines to 3.
int total;
result = new float[lines]; //lines: how many lines there are (assume it is passed through a parameter)
for (int i=0;i<lines;i++) 
{
    total = 0;

    for (int j=0;j<howmany;j++) //howmany is how many integers there are per line (assume it is passed again)
    {
        total += scores[i][j];
    }

    result[i] = (float)total/2;
}
```

Comment: It gives a value of 4, not 3. And i'm trying to divide 2 individually instead of doing it at the end